# group writable file not writable

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, file-permissions, group-policy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linux Group Permissions](https://superuser.com/questions/168428/linux-group-permissions)

I have a  file with following permissions

```
$ ls -l setup.txt
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data 10741 2011-10-12 14:15 setup.txt
```

I belong to www-data group

```
$ groups `whoami`
auniyal : auniyal adm dialout cdrom audio www-data plugdev lpadmin admin sambashare vboxusers
```

So I was thinking I should be able to write to that file but I am not

```
$ test -w setup.txt && echo "Writable" || echo "Not Writable"
Not Writable
```

so how is it determined that file is writable or not, because my thinking was if file is group writable and I belong to that group I should be able to write to that file?

and in case it helps directory is also group writable

```
$ ls -l ..
...
drwxrwxr-x 10 www-data www-data    4096 2011-12-07 09:42 timesite
...
```

Comment: Did you recently add yourself to the `www-data` group? If so, have you logged out since?

Comment: @Mat yes that was it,  you can put that as answer and I will select it, or I can close it as duplicate

Answer (score 4):

I needed to log-out and log-in again as I just added myself to www-data group

[Linux Group Permissions not being enforced correctly.](https://superuser.com/questions/168428/linux-group-permissions)