# CentOS7, SELinux, Apache, PHP-FPM: Access denied for file_put_contents to a user dir

Tags: apache-http-server, php, file-permissions, centos-7, selinux

I have a CentOS7/Apache multi-user (userdir) setup with SELinux enabled and the following directory structure:

```
/home/USER/public_html/resources/css
```

The whole `/home/USER` directory and everything underneath is owned by USER. All files and directories have a SELinux context of `httpd_user_content_t` except the aforementioned directory which I've set to `httpd_user_rw_content_t`. The apache server runs under the user apache and the apache user is member of the USER group. Everything under `/home/USER` has 0775 permissions (group writable). One of my scripts uses php's `file_put_contents` to create a file named `test_fpc.txt` in the `/home/USER/public_html/resources/css` directory but only if the directory is owned by `apache:apache` will the `file_put_contents` succeed. If the directory is owned by `USER:USER` the `file_put_contents` fails with `failed to open stream: Permission denied` warning. The audit log reads:

```
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1483602823.639:155208): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=no exit=-13 a0=7f0e5d9f1478 a1=241 a2=1b6 a3=73656372756f7365 items=2 ppid=855 pid=992 auid=4294967295 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="php-fpm" exe="/usr/sbin/php-fpm" subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key="apache_user_access"
type=CWD msg=audit(1483602823.639:155208):  cwd="/home/USER/public_html"
type=PATH msg=audit(1483602823.639:155208): item=0 name="/home/USER/public_html/resources/css/" inode=65290545 dev=08:12 mode=040775 ouid=1002 ogid=1002 rdev=00:00 obj=system_u:object_r:httpd_user_rw_content_t:s0 objtype=PARENT
type=PATH msg=audit(1483602823.639:155208): item=1 name="/home/USER/public_html/resources/css/test_fpc.txt" objtype=CREATE
```

When I login with the apache user with `sudo -u apache bash` and execute `echo "test" > /home/USER/public_html/resources/css/test_bash.txt` it works and the audit log output is:

```
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1483602552.156:155207): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=yes exit=3 a0=f607c0 a1=241 a2=1b6 a3=0 items=2 ppid=13539 pid=13540 auid=0 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=pts0 ses=207 comm="bash" exe="/usr/bin/bash" subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key="apache_user_access"
type=CWD msg=audit(1483602552.156:155207):  cwd="/home/USER/public_html"
type=PATH msg=audit(1483602552.156:155207): item=0 name="/home/USER/public_html/resources/css/" inode=65290545 dev=08:12 mode=040775 ouid=1002 ogid=1002 rdev=00:00 obj=system_u:object_r:httpd_user_rw_content_t:s0 objtype=PARENT
type=PATH msg=audit(1483602552.156:155207): item=1 name="test_bash.txt" inode=65273889 dev=08:12 mode=0100644 ouid=48 ogid=48 rdev=00:00 obj=unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_user_rw_content_t:s0 objtype=CREATE
```

I've also tried setting the context of the `/home/USER/public_html/resources/css` directory to `httpd_sys_rw_content_t` but it makes no difference.

I haven't tried setting `setsebool -P httpd_unified 1` as I'd really like to keep the current restrictive SELinux configuration and I feel like SELinux is not the real problem here. What could be the cause of the group writable directory not being writable by the apache user which IS a member of the USER group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to logout and log back in or restart the system. Found the clue here [Linux Group Permissions not being enforced correctly.](https://superuser.com/questions/168428/linux-group-permissions-not-being-enforced-correctly)